# String Compression in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, compression

I'm using the following code to make GET request and to store the result in the local variable using node.js, the result stored in the variable is intended to send as sms. How do I compress the data stored in the result prior to sending it as sms? Please help

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require("request")
var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
 response.send('Hello Cruel World!');
});
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var WEBHOOK_SECRET = "my secret here";
app.post('/telerivet/webhook', 
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
 function(req, res) {
  var secret = req.body.secret;
  if (secret !== WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
      res.status(403).end();
      return;
  }
  if (req.body.event == 'incoming_message') {
    var content = req.body.content;
    var from_number = req.body.from_number;
    var phone_id = req.body.phone_id;
  }
    request("http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/extract?url=http:  //"+content+"&extractor=LargestContentExtractor&output=text&extractImages=", function(error, response, data) {
    // do something with the message, e.g. send an autoreply
    res.json({
         messages: [
        { content:" " + data}
      ]
    });
   res.status(200).end();
     });
 }
 );  
  app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
 });
```

Comment: Compress what?  It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do.  What you want compressed?  Where that is in your code?  What type of compression you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compress the response to the browser, you will likely want to add a GZIP middleware package:

```
var compress = require('compression');

app.use(compress());
```

Comment: yes,i want to compress the strings (get reesponse from boilerspot) before sending it as sms ... how do i do this

Comment: Did you try the middleware?

Comment: No, can u pls explain a bit about it?

Comment: I think you should go to the site and read about it.  It compresses the response stream to from your server based on whether the end client can handle it or not.